# Catch the value of a textarea with codemirror and move to another textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I would like to know if anyone knows how I can get the value typed in a textarea with codemirror and insert at the same time into another textarea without codemirror. I know I need to use editor.getValue (); But how do I insert into the other textarea at the same time?

Comment: Please post some example code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

- You figured out the first half: [CodeMirror `.getValue()`](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getValue), to get text from first area.
- The second half is [jQuery `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to set the text to second area.

Click "Run code snippet" below to see a demo.

```js
var config = {
    lineNumbers: true
};
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($('#area1')[0], config);
editor.setSize(120,48);

$('#copy').click(function() {
    var text = editor.getValue(); // CodeMirror function to get content
    $('#area2').val(text); // jQuery function to set content
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.26.0/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.26.0/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cm">
  <textarea id="area1">
Hello
world
  </textarea>
</div>
<button id="copy">&darr; Copy content</button>
<div>
  <textarea id="area2"></textarea>
</div>
```